# Cartesian coordinates for the n-sphere - constraining angles?

Tags: manifolds, polar-coordinates, spheres, spherical-geometry

I have $n$ signals that are all oscillatory. I've estimated instantaneous phases using the Hilbert Transform (discarding amplitude), leaving me with a set of angles forming points on the $n$-sphere. All angles are ranged $[-\pi,\pi]$

I now need to transform these spherical points to the (n+1)-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system and found [this guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).

In short:
\begin{align}
x_1&=r\cos(\phi_1)\\
x_2&=r\sin(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)\\
x_3&=r\sin(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2)\cos(\phi_3)\\
\vdots \\
x_{n}&=r\sin(\phi_1)\cdots\sin(\phi_{n-1})\cos(\phi_{n})\\
x_{n+1}&=r\sin(\phi_1)\cdots\sin(\phi_{n-1})\sin(\phi_{n})\\
\end{align}

In my case, $r=1$. But in the guide it also says that $\phi_1,\phi_2,\cdots,\phi_{n-1}$ range over $[0,\pi]$ radians, whereas $\phi_n$ ranges over $[0,\pi]$.
Should I in my implementation take the absolute values of the first $(n-1)$ angles before transforming to Cartesian? E.g., $\phi_{10}=-\pi/2$ should be transformed to $\phi_{10}=\pi/2$ ?

I realize there's a [bunch of symmetry going on](https://researchcommons.waikato.ac.nz/handle/10289/1219) that I don't understand, but hopefully one of you can help me with the implementation :-)

EDIT: By following the procedure above, the first few coordinates will carry large weight, whereas the rest will be nearly zero. I wish to model my n-dimensional signals using the spherical uniform distribution, but with these coordinates this doesn't make sense. Once again I believe I am missing something?

Comment: Spherical coordinates on $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are basically$^*$ points in $[0, \pi]^{n-1} \times [0, 2\pi]$. These are points on a half-circle in all but the final coordinate. $^*$There is a measure zero set of overlap because these are closed intervals, which I'm not being careful with here.

Comment: If each coordinate is meant to be a point on a circle, then when considered all together, perhaps you want to describe a point on the $n$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^n = S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1$.